# context free grammar for a^n b^m

Tags: context-free-grammar

I'm trying to make a CFG for the language:

[image]

I did this:

```
S -> a S b b 
S -> epsilon
```

It fulfills the requirement, but is it correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "correct"? How can a context-free grammar be incorrect ?

Answer (score 1):

What if I wanted `abbb`? `n` is 1, therefore `2n` is 2 and `4n` is 4, `m` is 3, so `2n <= m < 4n`.  If you mean "does it create all the words in the language" as "is it correct", then no, it does not. Also, you are creating `epsilon` (zero `a` and zero `b`), but it's not correct that `2*0 <= 0 < 4*0` because zero is not less than zero (second part of the comparison).

Your grammar is creating only words where there is twice more `b` than `a`. However, the language contains also other words - you need to have between 2 times more `b` (including) and less than 4 times more `b` than `a`. Eg for `n = 2` your `m` can be 4, 5, 6 or 7.